Jetty 12 and http-forwarded not exposing client ip in HttpServletRequest
I have enabled the http-forwarded module with a custom forwarded for header we're getting from our load balancer (LB). However, when I attempt to access the HttpServletRequest's request.getRemoteHost(), it still returns the address of the LB and not the address in the header.
I wrote a simple helloworld program to show the headers being sent by the LB as per Jetty. In this case it's "X-Forwarded-For-YOUR-HOST" with the client's IP address. I have edited the start.d/http-forwarded.ini to set:
    --modules=http-forwarded
    jetty.httpConfig.forwardedOnly=false
    jetty.httpConfig.forwardedForHeader=X-Forwarded-For-YOUR-HOST


Restarted and in the same helloworld program, request.getRemoteHost/getRemoteIP still returns the IP of the LB while the header spit out shows the client ip.
Jetty's Logback entry also still returns the LB IP addr instead of the client IP in the header. (This might be a separate configuration issue.)
What am I missing?
